# Ruby on Rails Application Can Only Be Accessed by localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, localhost, passenger

I deploy an RoR application to my server, with an extra Apache2 virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ServerName ubuntu
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public
    PassengerEnabled off 
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9051
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9051

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      # Redirect all requests to the maintenance page if present
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
      RewriteRule ^.*$ /system/maintenance.html [L] 
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

and I start it using Passenger:

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9051 -e production -d
```

It's a Ubuntu server:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

And the port is listening:

```
plee@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsof -i :9051
[sudo] password for plee:
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   1016 plee    4u  IPv4 168135      0t0  TCP localhost:9051 (LISTEN)
nginx   1017 plee    4u  IPv4 168135      0t0  TCP localhost:9051 (LISTEN)
nginx   1017 plee    5u  IPv4 225556      0t0  TCP localhost:9051->localhost:44586 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    1018 plee    5u  IPv4 225555      0t0  TCP localhost:44586->localhost:9051 (ESTABLISHED)
```

The problem is that, my app can only be accessed by `http://localhost:9051`

If I try to connect from another machine using the server's IP address: `http://10.50.10.75:9051`

Google Chrome gives me:

```
Google Chrome could not connect to 10.50.10.75:9051
```

Please help me out!

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app accessible from 10.50.10.75:9051 from your local pc?

Access it from 10.50.10.75 not 10.50.10.75:9051 becoz the apache server which is proxying the app is running on port 80

Comment: No. It cannot even I type http://10.50.10.75:9051 from the apache server.

Comment: Can you access http://10.50.10.75 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying too hard. If you're on a server like you are, with apps running on various ports (and they're probably dev / staging, right?), and you simply want to access this app at port **:9501**, then the easy way is to ditch Apache. All you need is passenger, and you start it like this, **without the -a option**:

```
passenger start -p 9051 -e production -d
```

That's it; you're done. (You might want to make sure that your firewall, probably **ufw**, is not blocking that port, but that's the only other thing to test if you're still having problems.)

And a final piece of advice: Don't use a browser to test this kind of thing. Use **curl**. E.g.,

```
curl --head http://x.y.z.a:9051
```

Comment: Works like charm, thank!.  I don't think just following some guide without better understanding its meaning is enough.

Comment: Because I copied `passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9051 -e production -d` from somewhere and I thought it would work, which is stupid, I feel myself.

Comment: If you want to run the server with `-a 127.0.0.1`, you need to own a subdomain and config the virtual host file/site. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565194/apache2-configuration-that-allows-a-subdomain-point-to-an-machineport

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it access it on another port you need to add a virtualhost enty for that also you need to make apache listen to that port along with port 80

Here is what you need

```
#set the mod_passenger path **MAY BE DIFFERENT FOR YOU**
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8

#Listen to port 9501
Listen 9501

#add virtual host enty for port 9501
<VirtualHost *:9501>
        ServerName myservername
        DocumentRoot /var/www/tut/public

        <Directory /var/www/tut/public>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE**:No need to start the passenger from command line now, this should already do it.

This worked for me.

Comment: If I put a slash, when I restart apache, it gives me `Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter. Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'.`

Comment: No. It does NOT make any difference with or without the "/".

Comment: I just tried `http://10.50.10.75/`, it's accessible, but all assets (images/css) files cannot be loaded.  BTW, I'm not supposed to use the ip address without a port number. because there will be other apps running on different ports.  I have to use `http://10.50.10.75:9501`